# LuaJit FFI Return string from C function to Lua?

Tags: c, string, lua, ffi, luajit

Say I have this C function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) const char* GetStr()
{
    static char buff[32]

    // Fill the buffer with some string here

    return buff;
}
```

And this simple Lua module:

```
local mymodule = {}

local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
    const char* GetStr();
]]

function mymodule.get_str()
    return ffi.C.GetStr()
end

return mymodule
```

How can I get the returned string from the C function as a Lua string here:

```
local mymodule = require "mymodule"

print(mymodule.get_str())
```

Comment: What are you getting it as now? What does that code do that you don't want?

Comment: Currently when I print I get `cdata<const char *>: 0x00000001` instead of the string. From the documentation I'm supposed to use `ffi.string(buff [,len])` to get the actual string. But when I do that the application crashes.

Comment: Show the `ffi.string` call you were trying, and the backtrace/etc. from the crash. Ideally also the code that fills the string.

Comment: @EtanReisner Turns out that this was happening because of one simple mistake in my code (one of those copy>paste mistakes). I apologize for the inconvenience. The example works fine now with the answer from hugomg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`ffi.string`](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html#ffi_string) function apparently does the conversion you are looking for.

```
function mymodule.get_str()
    local c_str = ffi.C.GetStr()
    return ffi.string(c_str)
end
```

If you are getting a crash, then make sure that your C string is null terminated and, in your case, has at most 31 characterss (so as to not overflow its buffer).

Comment: I tried that but the application crashes. I thought I was doing something wrong :-/

Comment: maybe your string is too long and is overflowing the buffer?

Comment: Turns out that I miscalculated something and an integer was returned instead. Thank you all for your answers and I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: No need to apologize.  There is always the possibility that the question will be useful for someone in the future. :)

Comment: what to do if the string is longer than 31 chars?

Comment: The 31 characters limitation is because OP's code stores the string on a 32-byte buffer. You should be able to pass strings of any length to `ffi.string`

Comment: please note, ffi.string also has a second 'len' parameter, so it can also be used with non-null-terminated strings.