# how to get string insted of char pointer in Lua

Tags: lua, freepascal, lua-table, ffi

I have a big problem....can't solve it.
I have free pascal program and lua script.

```
function getString(i:integer):PChar;public; stdcall;
begin
//something to do 
Result:=strnew(PChar('newString'));
end
```

by passing the registration functions there is Lua implementation

```
ffi.cdef
[[
char*__stdcall getString(i:integer);
]]
local str =ffi.C.getString(5)
print (tostring(str))
```

instead of 'newString' I get address of cdata. Please anybody help me to understand this moment. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tostring` is being passed an address, and so gives you the string representation of that address. You need `ffi.string` instead.

```
local str = ffi.string(ffi.C.getString(5))
```

Now `str` is a Lua string containing what was returned by your Pascal code.

Your other perhaps bigger problem is surely that you are allocating a string on the Pascal module's heap with no obvious way of deallocating it.

Comment: *Note*: I know nothing of Lua and based my answer on its documentation and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597155/luajit-ffi-return-string-from-c-function-to-lua  So there may be syntax inaccuracies. I'm sure you know Lua so will be able to cope.

Comment: How about some detail as to what does happen. Could perfectly well be a defect in your Pascal code.

Comment: Thanks, Everything is ok ! It was other mistake ))))) Thank you

Comment: Good. Glad I wasn't going mad.